# How to solve ANR on Android firemonkey

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

On my Android application develop with Firemonkey 10.4.1, I see a lot of ANR in my Google Play Console.

The first one is :

> Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the
> touched window has not finished processing certain input events that
> were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago. waitqueue length = 1, head.seq
> = 14881924, Wait queue head age: 6480.1ms.)

And the second one :

> Input dispatching timed out (9a5f6ef
> com.xxx.myapp/com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity
> (server) is not responding. Waited 10003ms for
> FocusEvent(hasFocus=true))

My app contain a TMapView, show bitmap downloaded from my server (or take and upload). I change the loading method by a thread instead of task, but it's same.

I don't have any detail on how to get it. When I test in Android 32/64 I never got a ANR.

Does something exist to trace these error ? a event where I can add log ?

Comment: You say that you get an ANR in Android, but also when you test in Android 32/54 you don't get an ANR.  Please calrify what does and does nto have the problem.  If you compile the code and run it on Windows (if there are no Andropid dependencies) is there still a problem?

Comment: I don't have any problem on my device, I see these ANR on the Google Play Console, so the user who use my app get it.

Comment: Do you use ads in your app? If so, do they show when you are testing? It might also help to provide the complete ANR log

Comment: I don't have any ads, I load marker on a map with a thread, and when you click on a marker I load a bitmap

Comment: @Bosshoss - I see similar errors in Play Store for my FMX Android app, built with Delphi 11. In addition to yours, I also see this one "Waited 10002ms for MotionEvent". Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Hans not really, I think it's not very stable on some device and that's really difficult to find where is the problem and fix it. You can use grijjy on your app to have more details on error, may be it will help you.